# Discord Meta Tags in Next.JS Router

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, react-typescript

The NextJS Router has a something called `metadata`, it was a new way to place a Title, Description, and more.

[image]

The problem is, what is the Meta Tags for the Discord URL Embed to place for the metadata without using the old Meta Property (`<meta property="og:title" content="Site Title" />`).

I'm expecting the new Metadata to format the embed in Discord, without use the meta property as shown in above.